# Значки в ListView без использования анонимных типов

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно получить список ListViewItems в ListView. Однако, поскольку туда добавляются лишь анонимные типы, сделать это невозможно.

ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="IconsListView" BorderThickness="0">

<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>

<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Width="90" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="20"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="64" Height="64" Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="NameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Добавление элементов:

```
IconsListView.Items.Add(new { Name = "Icon 1", Image = "icon.ico" });
IconsListView.Items.Add(new { Name = "Icon 2", Image = "icon.ico" });
IconsListView.Items.Add(new { Name = "Icon 3", Image = "icon.ico" });
IconsListView.Items.Add(new { Name = "Icon 4", Image = "icon.ico" });
IconsListView.Items.Add(new { Name = "Icon 5", Image = "icon.ico" });
IconsListView.Items.Add(new { Name = "Icon 6", Image = "icon.ico" });
```

То что не работает и нужно решить:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (ListViewItem item in IconsListView.Items)
        MessageBox.Show(VisualTreeHelper.GetContentBounds(item).ToString());
}
```

Comment: А сделать полноценный класс из этого: `new { Name = "...", Image = "..." }` - религия не позволяет? )

Comment: ну или на крайняк используйте `dynamic`

Comment: А что конкретно означает «не работает» и почему вы думаете, что в этом виноват анонимный класс?

Comment: @VladD,
Потому что в Items хранятся переменные моего анонимного типа и при попытке приведения к Visual выдаётся соответствующее исключение.

Comment: @Андрей, где использовать dynamic то? В цикле что ли?

Comment: @Андрей, сделать полноценный класс - это как раз единственное решение что я вижу. Но вопрос в том, как это организовать. Просто наследовать от ListViewItem и добавить туда нужные свойства? Так это не сработает...

Comment: Наследоваться не нужно, просто создайте класс и добавляйте его экземпляры

Comment: А разве когда я потом буду проходиться по Items мне удастся привести к Visual?

Comment: @Андрей, мне же в итоге нужно приведение в Visual. Если добавлять в ListView Items класс, который от Visual не унаследован, то приведение не будет возможно и, следовательно, результат не будет достигнут. Нужно наследовать что-то.

Comment: `foreach (object item in IconsListView.Items) { (MyClass)item ... }` - так, или так: `foreach (MyClass item in IconsListView.Items.Cast<MyClass>()) { ... }` попробуйте

Comment: > Если добавлять в ListView Items класс, который от Visual - с чего вы взяли, вы же биндитесь к конкретным свойствам: `Text="{Binding Name}"`

Comment: @Андрей, дак я вот какое действие хочу выполнить: `VisualTreeHelper.GetContentBounds(item)`. Для этого привожу к Visual.
> Если добавлять в ListView Items класс, который от Visual не унаследован, то приведение не будет возможно - да речь тут вообще не о Binding, который ясно дело работает. Посмотрите на обработчик ContentRendered.

Comment: Смахивает на Problem XY. Зачем вам вообще понадобилось это: `VisualTreeHelper.GetContentBounds(item)`? И что вы ожидаете увидеть когда приводите результат в `.ToString()` ?

Comment: @Андрей, Я упростил задачу. Не вникайте. За этим больше тысячи строк. Нужно вывести этот результат.

Comment: Если вы намекаете на то, что я предоставил недостаточно сведений о задаче, то я так не считаю. Вы можете просто скопировать представленный код в проект и самому пронаблюдать проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что в WPF есть разница между данными и UI. В `Items` вы кладёте данные (кстати, лучше класть из в `ItemsSource`). Тип этих данных не имеет особого значения. На основании этих данных `ListView` генерирует `ListViewItem`'ы, которые и содержат визуальную часть.

Вы хотите каким-то образом залезть в `Items`, получить назад ровно те данные, которые вы туда сами и положили, и превратить из в `ListViewItem`'ы.

Это можно, но требует некоторой магии.

```
var generator = IconsListView.ItemContainerGenerator;
foreach (var item in IconsListView.Items)
{
    // item -- наш элемент данных, получим по нему визуальный элемент
    var container = (ListViewItem)generator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    var size = container.RenderSize;
    var offset = container.TranslatePoint(new Point(), IconsListView);
    var rect = new Rect(offset, size);
    // ...
}
```

Точный тип данных, который кладётся в `Items`, не имеет значения.

Comment: Спасибо. Про тип данных и разделение между UI и данными мне было известно) Я именно и хотел получить вот эту вот "магию" по преобразовыванию моего анонимного типа в визуальный.

Comment: Не подскажете вот ещё с чем: Как получить Rect описывающий конкретный ListViewItem? VisualTreeHelper.GetContentBounds() возвращает Rect.Empty в моём случае.

Comment: @D.Stark: А проверьте `ActualWidth` и `ActualHeight`, а? Кстати, если они равны нулю, то у вас таки нулевого размера элементы в этот момент.

Comment: Размер верный. Как у ListViewItem так и у ListView.

Comment: Да и для ListView не удаётся bounds получить.

Comment: @D.Stark: Окей, а так? (Обновил ответ.)

Comment: Так работает, спасибо. Вообще о таком способе не знал.

Comment: Делал Adorner для прямоугольника множественного выделения элементов ListView. Не знаете, кстати, как называется такая штука по-грамотному? Ну, такое ещё в Проводнике Windows реализовано. Назвал Selection rectangle.

Comment: @D.Stark: У меня знакомые называют такое «выделение резиночкой» :)

Comment: @D.Stark: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Comment: Не поможете разобраться вот ещё с чем: как различить 2 события mousedown? Одно событие физически выглядит как down-up, а другое как down-up-down (последнее используется для захвата и перетаскивания элементов drag-and-drop). Оба события рассматриваются .NET как MouseDown, но ведь физически это не так... Небольшое пояснение: простое нажатие на одну кнопку мыши выполняемое по элементу вообще событием не является - почему так?

Comment: @D.Stark: Я навскидку не соображу, к сожалению. Может, имеет смысл задать отдельным вопросом с более подробным описанием?

Comment: Да, я тоже так думаю. Поэтому вот ссылка, если вы не против помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671730/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-mousedown-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9