# Обработка MouseDown событий на тачпаде

Tags: c#, wpf

Возьму некоторые обозначения прежде чем начну вопрос:

- `down` - физическое нажатие на кнопку тачпада (левую)
- `up` - физическое отпускание кнопки тачпада (левой)

---

Есть 2 случая, когда происходит MouseDown событие с использованием тачпада:

1. `down-up` - по сути, щелчок мышкой (аналогия с click для button); при этом после вызова MouseDown вызывается сразу MouseUp. Временной интервал между физическим DOWN и UP фиксирован по максимальному значению (при его превышении, происходит только MouseUp).
2. `down-up-down` - н-р, используется для захвата и перетаскивания элементов (drag-and-drop); MouseUp здесь вовсе не происходит - только MouseDown. Временной интервал между всеми тремя действиями опять же, есс-но, фиксирован.

Как отличить первый случай от второго?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61635/discussion-on-question-by-d-stark--mousedown---).